# PHP - File_Get_contents/Curl on large file - Clear Memory afterwards

Tags: php, laravel, apache, curl

I'm doing some tests on my server and it involves importing a large 2gb file then decoding it to an array. However each time i load the page, my system memory is reduced by 2gb and it is not being freed up. So if i reload the same page 10 times, i'm down 20gb of memory.

The only way i can clear it afterwards is:

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2.service
```

is there any way to remove the file/variable from memory after is it loaded. I tried both file_get_contents and curl. Same issue.

```
$file_data = file_get_contents($file_path);
$data = json_decode($file_data, true);

//DO_SOMETHING

$file_data = null;
$data = null;
```

Comment: Are you sure you're waiting for the script to fully complete before trying to reload?

Comment: yes. The page fully loads and cpu operations back to idle.

Comment: A leak in this case might indicate there's something that prevents the script from terminating e.g. an open file handle or something else that PHP is waiting on before it can close the process. If you are using FPM it might be worth trying to unset any large variables and running [`gc_collect_cycles`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gc-collect-cycles.php) before the code ends to check if that works.